# Linux network by serial port

Tags: linux, networking, ip, serial

I need help to configure a serial port (/dev/ttyS1 or /dev/ttyUSB0 is the same) to communicate vs other hosts via IP (without modem). Some years ago it was possible ma I don't remember how.
Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

PPP using `pppd` is likely the most standard method (supported on many different platforms), and pppd works more-or-less the same whether a modem is involved or not.

Unfortunately the general [TLDP "PPP HOWTO"](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/PPP-HOWTO/) hasn't been updated for ages (like most of TLDP), so it still refers to ancient Linux 1.x and 2.x kernels – but the parts involving actual pppd configuration will still be 80% the same today, especially the page on [direct connections](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/PPP-HOWTO/direct.html). The [TLDP "Leased line HOWTO"](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Leased-Line/pppd.html) may also be useful.

An even older alternative to PPP is SLIP, using the `slattach` command. While PPP is cross-platform, SLIP is only implemented on Unix systems, but may be simpler to configure.

Comment: SLIP implementations exist for other operating systems. But it is ancient and very difficult to get to work on any modern OS that isn't Unix (and that includes Linux as well). pppd is almost as old, but as it became one of the de-facto dailup standards for (a)DSL it is much better supported and is a lot easier to get documentation for. I ran several SLIP networks in de late 80's myself and switching to pppd was a no-brainer when that became available.